# how to find all the links on a page?

Tags: xpath

please tell me the expression xpath, with which you can find all the items  on the web page. ie I need to find a link at any level of nesting.

similarly:

```
xpath('a')
xpath('*/a')
xpath('*/*/a')
xpath('*/*/*/a')
xpath('*/*/*/*/a')
......
.....
.........
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find your answer, along with loads of others at

http://courses.ischool.berkeley.edu/i290-14/s05/lecture-4/allslides.xhtml

Basically, you need to use

```
//a
```

Exempt from the mentioned link:

> You can match elements that aren't direct children with the "//"
>   (double forward slash).
>
> This looks through the descendants of the "current context".
>
> For example:
>
> /section//cite will match all 'cite' elements that are descendants of
>   'section'. But:
>
> //cite will match all 'cite' elements in the document.